# laravel Two date between query

Tags: php, laravel

mysql table columns **"startTime", "endTime"**

1. Today: 2021-04-30
2. startTime: 2021-04-29
3. endTime: 2021-05-03

How can I pull the current date data between two columns ?

Fixed: whereRaw('"'.$today.'" between startTime and endTime')

Comment: You can use diff between dates. You should give more context to your question

Comment: [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Comment: @aynber, whereBetween will also compare time, he provides Y-m-d format

Comment: @PsyLogic We don't know if those fields are date fields or datetime fields. If all data is date and not datetime, then it's not an issue

Comment: yes if that the case, it will works good

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::whereDate('startTime' '>=' now())->whereDate('endTime','<=', now())->get()
```